# Amadeus Fare Rule request

Tags: amadeus

Amedeus Api call,
I'm passing "include=detailed-fare-rules" in url encoded

*https://test.api.amadeus.com/v2/shopping/flight-offers/pricing?include=detailed-fare-rules&originLocationCode=ISB&destinationLocationCode=KHI&departureDate=2022-05-01&returnDate=2022-05-18&adults=1&max=5*

```
but it return the below error.
{
    "errors": [
        {
            "status": 404,
            "title": "No routing found for this resource/method/version combination.",
            "code": 700,
            "source": {
                "pointer": "uri"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Flight Offers Price API supports a POST method and only the `include` and `forceClass` are allowed as query parameters. Please check the [API reference](https://developers.amadeus.com/self-service/category/air/api-doc/flight-offers-price/api-reference) of the API.

The correct way to call the API to return the fare rules is the following:

`POST https://test.api.amadeus.com/v1/shopping/flight-offers/pricing?include=detailed-fare-rules`

with the following body:

```
{
   "data":{
      "type":"flight-offers-pricing",
      "flightOffers":[
          .....
      ]
   }
}
```

In the `flightOffers` you have to pass the flight offer returned by the [Flight Offers Search API](https://developers.amadeus.com/self-service/category/air/api-doc/flight-offers-search/api-reference) for which you are looking the fare rules.